# create custom woocommerce checkout template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to override the checkout template.

I've copied: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php` to `wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`

but it still reads the original template. and idea what im missing or doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Are you using this template in child theme or parent theme?

Comment: @George a theme i bought.

Comment: Are you working on child theme or parent theme?

Comment: using the parent theme

Comment: what you are trying to change in `form-checkout.php` file? can you post your code?

Comment: well nothing yet. just added `<h1>TEST</h1>` above the `<form>` tag for now. I want to eventually change the layout